# Missing form after Minimize - Windows form application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I try to minimize my form to system tray but when I do, the form disappears and the notification icon doesnt work :(

What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
        Me.Visible = False
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub NotifyIcon1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.DoubleClick, NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipClicked
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    Me.Visible = True
    NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

I initialize NotificationIcon text, balloon tip and other stuff in the aspx page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's in C# but the idea should be obvious :)

```
private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
    }
}

void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
    this.Show();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Comment: Idea was obvious but my mistake was forgetting to initialize Notification icon, in Form_Load

Comment: Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        Button3.PerformClick() ' BUMP ALL

    End Sub

Button clicks every 60 seconds but when minimized, it doesnt do anything, when I resized the form (maximize) then it works again.

what is the reason for this?

Comment: Because the implementation of PerformClick checks button's property CanSelect and if it's false - does nothing: public void PerformClick()
{
    if (base.CanSelect)
    {

Comment: How can I fix this in my occasion?

Comment: Just call the method which you have subscribed for Button.Click event (button3_Click(null, null)) instead of calling PerformClick, or redesign your classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot user472157

 Button3_Click(Sender, e)

solved it

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    NotifyIcon1.Icon = Me.Icon
End Sub
```

In the tutorial it was not telling me to include Icon in the Form Load, that was the reason.

Problem solved!  :)